# How do I remove certain leading characters from text

Tags: sql, t-sql

How do I remove characters =,?,+,- and @ from a text column, but only if they appear as the prefix in a string?

For example:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `#Stackoverflow` | `Stackoverflow` |
| `@#StackOverflow` | `Stackoverflow` |
| `=?+-Stackoverflow` | `Stackoverflow` |

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean, prefix to each word in a text or Prefix to the whole text?

Comment: More detail required. What if it's `Stack@#Overflow` or `=Stack=Overflow` or `@?Stack ?@Overflow`

Comment: Prefix to whole text.  I want to handle the case only when =@?Stackoverflow . Any special character in the middle of whole text is allowed

Comment: @akhil what you describe sounds like what I implemented in answer below - did you try it out, does it work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the assumption "prefix" means to remove the characters to the left of the first non-special character, but special characters later in the string should remain:

```
with data as (
    select '@#StackOverflow' string union all 
    select '=?+Stack#@Overflow' union all 
    select 'Stack#@Overflow'
)
select * , Stuff(string,1,p.pos-1,'')
from data
cross apply(values(PatIndex('%[^=?+-@#]%',string)))p(pos);
```

| Original | Fixed |
| --- | --- |
| @#StackOverflow | StackOverflow |
| =?+Stack#@Overflow | Stack#@Overflow |
| Stack#@Overflow | Stack#@Overflow |